# How to fix digitalRead

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

So my problem is that after like two readings of digital pin 6,7 the pin stays on forever for some reason here's my code. I can't seem to find why does it happen I tried to add some delay(x); but it didn't help .. never happend for pin 5 which is even more strange to me... any help will be appreciated

```
#include <Stepper.h>

int obstaclePin = A0;
int obstaclePin2 = A1;
int obstaclePin3 = A2;

const int button1Pin = 5;
const int button2Pin = 6;
const int button3Pin = 7; 

const int stepsPerRevolution = 80;

Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 50, 51, 52, 53);
Stepper myStepper2(stepsPerRevolution, 46, 47, 48, 49);
Stepper myStepper3(stepsPerRevolution, 42, 43, 44, 45);

void setup() {
  myStepper.setSpeed(100);
  myStepper2.setSpeed(100);
  myStepper3.setSpeed(100);

  pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);

  pinMode(obstaclePin, INPUT);    // sets the sensor pin
  pinMode(obstaclePin2, INPUT);    // sets the sensor pin
  pinMode(obstaclePin3, INPUT);    // sets the sensor pin

  pinMode(button1Pin, INPUT_PULLUP);    // declare pushbutton as input
  pinMode(button2Pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(button3Pin, INPUT_PULLUP);

  Serial.begin(9600);    // initialize the serial port:
}
int counter = 0;
void loop() {
  while(true){
    if(digitalRead(button1Pin)==0){
      counter = 1;
      break;
    }
    else if(digitalRead(button2Pin)==0){
      counter = 2;
      break;
    }
    else if(digitalRead(button3Pin)==0){
      counter = 3;
      break;
    }
  }
  while(counter!=0){
    digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
//*******************************************************************************************************************************************************
    if(counter==1){
      if(analogRead(obstaclePin)<=400){
        counter=0;
        delay(100);
        break;
      }
      Serial.println("Motor 1");
      myStepper.step(1);
    }
//*******************************************************************************************************************************************************
    else if(counter==2){
      if(analogRead(obstaclePin2)<=400){
        counter=0;
        delay(100);
        break;
      }
      Serial.println("Motor 2");
      myStepper2.step(1);
    }
//*******************************************************************************************************************************************************
    else if(counter==3){
      if(digitalRead(obstaclePin3)==0){
        counter=0;
        delay(100);
        break;
      }
      Serial.println("Motor 3");
      myStepper3.step(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have the same problem I  had see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55909270/stuck-in-while-loop-arduino if this can help you.

Comment: Thanks but this won't help me since I can get out of the while loop but the button is always being red as low .. in some cases only

Comment: @MartinLukas so then they actually stay off forever...what is the circuit like for your button? Are you debouncing it? I don't see any such thing in your code.

Comment: That's a good point actually

Comment: Using loops inside loop() normally makes everything more complex than necessary. In your case, buttons are not read again until the corresponding obstacle pin or distance is reached.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to achieve ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debouncing the inputs is the solution here.